# How would I trim extraneous code to isolate varying strings of text in Python?

Tags: python, search, replace

I'm a novice coder and am looking to create a script that would strip all the javascript from a source file to isolate varying strings of text.

I.E. I have this code

```
terms[1] = "affect heuristic";

defs[1] = "The mental shortcut of addressing a question as &quot;How do I feel about this?&quot; instead of &quot;What do I think about this?&quot;";
media[1] = ""; // Media Array
term_audio[1] = ""; // Term_Audio Array
images[1] = ""; // Images Array

        //
terms[2] = "agonism";

defs[2] = "Defending one's own survival interests against other organisms.";
media[2] = ""; // Media Array
term_audio[2] = ""; // Term_Audio Array
images[2] = ""; // Images Array
```

And I want to strip everything away except for the terms and definitions within the quotation marks and be able to apply it to a list containing n terms and definitions, so the output would be

> affect heuristic, The mental shortcut of addressing a question as "How do I feel about this?" instead of "What do I think about this?"
>
> agonism, definition here,
>
> nth term, nth definition

How would I do this?

Thank you!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to accomplish this:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> input_str = """
... terms[1] = "affect heuristic";
... 
... defs[1] = "The mental shortcut of addressing a question as &quot;How do I feel about this?&quot; instead of &quot;What do I think about this?&quot;";
... media[1] = ""; // Media Array
... term_audio[1] = ""; // Term_Audio Array
... images[1] = ""; // Images Array
... 
...         //
... terms[2] = "agonism";
... 
... defs[2] = "Defending one's own survival interests against other organisms.";
... media[2] = ""; // Media Array
... term_audio[2] = ""; // Term_Audio Array
... images[2] = ""; // Images Array
... """
>>> 
>>> res = re.sub(r'".*"', '', input_str)
>>> print(res, sep='\n')

terms[1] = ;

defs[1] = ;
media[1] = ; // Media Array
term_audio[1] = ; // Term_Audio Array
images[1] = ; // Images Array

        //
terms[2] = ;

defs[2] = ;
media[2] = ; // Media Array
term_audio[2] = ; // Term_Audio Array
images[2] = ; // Images Array

>>>
```